# Xceed Docx returns blank document

Tags: c#, .net, docx, xceed

noob here, i want to export a report as docx file using the xceed docx, but it returns blank document (empty)

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        Xceed.Words.NET.DocX document = Xceed.Words.NET.DocX.Create(stream);
        Xceed.Words.NET.Paragraph p = document.InsertParagraph();

        p.Append("Hello World");

        document.Save();

        return File(stream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "DOCHK.docx");
```

please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The problem:

While your data has been written to the `MemoryStream`, the internal "stream pointer" or cursor (in old-school terminology, think of it as like a tape-head) is at the end of the data you've written:

Before `document.Save()`:

```
stream = [_________________________...]
ptr    =  ^
```

After calling `document.Save()`:

```
stream = [<xml><p>my word document</p><p>the end</p></xml>_________________________...]
ptr    =                                                  ^
```

When you call `Controller.File( Stream, String )` it will then proceed to read on from the current `ptr` location and so only read blank data:

```
stream = [<xml><p>my word document</p><p>the end</p></xml>from_this_point__________...]
ptr    =                                                  ^
```

(In reality it won't read anything at all because `MemoryStream` specifically does not allow reading beyond its internal length limit which by default is the amount of data written to it so far)

If you reset the `ptr` to the start of the stream, then when the stream is read the returned data will start from the beginning of written data:

```
stream = [<xml><p>my word document</p><p>the end</p></xml>_________________________...]
ptr    =  ^
```

### Solution:

You need to reset the MemoryStream to position 0 before reading data from the stream:

```
using Xceed.Words.NET;

// ...

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
DocX document = DocX.Create( stream );
Paragraph p = document.InsertParagraph();

p.Append("Hello World");

document.Save();

stream.Seek( 0, SeekOrigin.Begin ); // or `Position = 0`.

return File( stream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "DOCHK.docx" );
```